# Error: Unterminated quoted string during PHP exec

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I'm using the `exec` function in PHP to make mysql dump a query's contents into a CSV file.

Here's my code:

```
$outfile = '/home/dotslash/file.csv';
$emails_table = 'all_emails';

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$dbname = 'test';

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(emailid), COUNT(emailid), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT offers) FROM '" . $emails_table . "' GROUP BY emailid INTO OUTFILE '" . $outfile . "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";

exec("mysql -h$host -u$user -p$pass $dbname -e '$query'");
```

And I'm getting this error: `sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

I know the problem is escaping when the string is being passed from PHP to bash, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: Is this by accident: '\n';";   There seems to be an extra ;

Comment: @VictorPerez What makes you think so? The first semi-colon is for MySQL. The second is for PHP.

Comment: Just visual compared to how I code. I've never used a semi-colon like this other than to end a statement. You seem to have enough reputation to make me think you know what you're doing, so I started looking at possible typo's :-)

Comment: @VictorPerez LOL, I don't know what "enough reputation" means. And we all can make small mistakes and trip up. :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant you seem to know what you're doing more than me (not being sarcastic, still new 'round here) :-)

Comment: `..LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';"` prevent `"` replace

Comment: Your issue is certainly with this part: `ENCLOSED BY '\"' `

Comment: @MaggsWeb Thanks. That was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you connected to your database? In your script it doesn't seem to... Add this string after your database informations:

```
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

And at the end of the script add:

```
mysql_close($con);
```

So your code would look like:

```
  $outfile = '/home/dotslash/file.csv';
$emails_table = 'all_emails';

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$dbname = 'test';

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(emailid), COUNT(emailid), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT offers) FROM '" . $emails_table . "' GROUP BY emailid INTO OUTFILE '" . $outfile . "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";

exec("mysql -h$host -u$user -p$pass $dbname -e '$query'");

mysql_close($con);
```

There may be a problem in your SQL with the

```
   ... ENCLOSED BY '\"' ...
```

Try to replace it with:

```
$enc = '"';

... ENCLOSED BY '".$enc."' ...
```

So your final code would be:

```
$outfile = '/home/dotslash/file.csv';
    $emails_table = 'all_emails';

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';
    $dbname = 'test';

    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        mysql_select_db($dbname);

$enc = '"';

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(emailid), COUNT(emailid), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT offers) FROM '" . $emails_table . "' GROUP BY emailid INTO OUTFILE '" . $outfile . "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '".$enc."' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";

    exec("mysql -h$host -u$user -p$pass $dbname -e '$query'");

mysql_close($con);
```

If this doesn't resolve your problem try to use concatenation to pass the $query var, like this:

```
exec("mysql -h$host -u$user -p$pass $dbname -e ".$query."");
```

Also try to var_dump your $query like this:

```
var_dump($query);
```

Because you may need to fetch your results before passing them to the exec command.

Pro-Tip: Check if your SQL command is correct passing the command directly from your database on phpmyadmin and check if it trow errors.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the extensive answer! I was able to make it work by enclosing `$query` in double quotes *and* escaping the double quote in ENCLOSED BY as `\\\"`.

Comment: Perfect! Let me know if you have other problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

do a var_dump of $query and after put your returned string by var_dump in sql console of phpmyadmin or other sqlmanager and see the result.

Sry for my english am french

Comment: Good suggestion, but I don't think it's helping. One problem, among many others, is that the query is passed as `'$query'` to exec. You can't replicate this using `var_dump` and pasting it to MySQL console.